# Django Custom Authentication Not Authenticating Custom User

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-authentication

So I am trying to build a website using Django where there are two separate user bases, one is `user` and the other is `agent`. Now I imported `User` from `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` and have a separate model for `Agent`. What I want is for there to be different login urls for `users` and `agents`. An `agent` can be an `agent` without having to be registered as a `user`. Now I have tried this code, and what this does is after trying to log in using `agent` credentials, it logs in and returns the correct html page but doesn't even authenticate if those credentials are right or wrong. Like the `agent_login` is still `logging me in` even after providing it with the wrong credentials. Now I want to know what the problem is and how to fix it so that it works properly.

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phonenumber = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

class Agent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'Images/')
    bio = models.TextField()
    instagram = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    twitter = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    facebook = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='')

    def set_password(self, raw_password):
        self.password = make_password(raw_password)
        self.save()  

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} Agent Profile'
```

My forms.py:

```
class AgentSignInForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = forms.PasswordInput()
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        username = cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        return cleaned_data
```

My views.py:

```
def agent_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AgentSignInForm(request.POST)
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        agent = AgentBackend.authenticate(request)
        return render(request, 'users/agent_dashboard.html', {'agent': agent})
    else:
        form = AgentSignInForm()
    return render(request, 'users/agent_login.html', {'form': form,})

    
class AgentDashboard(DetailView):
    model = Agent
    template_name = 'users/agent_dashboard.html'
    slug_field = 'slug'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        agent = self.get_object()
        properties = Property.objects.filter(agent=agent)
        context['properties'] = properties
        return context
```

My settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "users.backends.AgentBackend",
]
```

My backends.py:

```
from .models import Agent
from contextlib import suppress
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

class AgentBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        # Skip authentication attempts without credentials
        if username is None or password is None:
            return

        # Get agent by name, check the password hash and return it if everything is ok
        with suppress(Agent.DoesNotExist):  
            agent = Agent.objects.get(name=username)
            if check_password(password, agent.password):
                return agent
        return None

    def get_user(self, slug):
        # Fetch and return agent if it exists
        with suppress(Agent.DoesNotExist):
            return Agent.objects.get(slug=slug)
        return None
```

My admin.py:

```
class AgentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if 'password' in form.changed_data:
            obj.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

admin.site.register(Agent, AgentAdmin)
```

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Ok. Can you please tell me the current status of the problem.

Comment: I followed @VonC's solution and it returns `cannot access local variable 'agent' where it is not associated with a value`

Comment: Can you check code at the end in the my answer.

Comment: try this `with suppress(Agent.DoesNotExist):
    agent = Agent.objects.get(name=username)
    if (agent):
        if check_password(password, agent.password):
            return agent  # Return agent if credentials are correct
        
        else:
            return None 
    else:
        return None`

Answer (score 0):

## 1)

Frist make sure your normal view functions to look like below. (expect login view and register view).

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def my_view(request):
```

## 2)

Then,

1)
You only authenticate(check if pass and u_name is correct) them, You should log them in.
Change below code to,

```py
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        agent = AgentBackend.authenticate(request)
```

.
Like below -

```py
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
agent = AgentBackend.authenticate(request=request,username=username,password=password)
if agent is not None:
    login(request,agent,backend='AgentBackend')
    return render(request, 'users/agent_dashboard.html', {'agent': agent})
else:
    form = AgentSignInForm()
    return render(request, 'users/agent_login.html', {'form': form,})
```

You need to log them in(save them as logged in users in DB).

## 3)

Update backends.py code as below.

```
with suppress(Agent.DoesNotExist):
    agent = Agent.objects.get(name=username)
    if (agent):
        if check_password(password, agent.password):
            return agent  # Return agent if credentials are correct
        
        else:
            return None 
    else:
        return None
```

.

**You maybe already logged in current browser, so try using new incognito browser window.**

Comment: doesn't work, I added 
`agent = authenticate(request=request,username=username,password=password)
        if agent is not None:
            login(request, agent, backend='AgentBackend')`
But even if I provide wrong credentials, it still logs me in.

Comment: still doesn't work :)

Comment: does  it still logs you in?

Comment: make sure to fully restart the server, use the correct indents.

Comment: Still it logs me in every time, restarted the server fully using correct indents, doesn't work .

Comment: Try using incognito mode of the browser.

Comment: Did the problem fixed ?

Comment: No bro still same

Comment: Can you show us your views.py code?

Comment: I updated the answer, can you check it..

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/customizing/):

> The order of AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS matters, so if the same username and password is valid in multiple backends, Django will stop processing at the first positive match.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "users.backends.AgentBackend",
]
```

In your settings you are giving preference to Django's default authentication where your user gets authenticated and your custom authentication is not touched hence always logging in.

You just need to swap the order and it will give your custom authentication priority and if it fails then it will use default authentication of django.

Comment: even when I swap them, it is still logging me in even when I use incorrect credentials and  in my views I passed context to use at `agent_dashboard.html` but after logging in with correct credentials, I cannot use those context.

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering `agent_dashboard.html` even if there is no agent. Render or redirect only if `authenticate` function returns agent instance.
Also instead of rendering the template, redirect to the agent dashboard page after successful login

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import login

def agent_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = AgentSignInForm(request.POST)
       username = request.POST['username']
       password = request.POST['password']
       agent = AgentBackend.authenticate(request, username, password)
       if not agent:
          return HttpResponse("Invalid user credentials")
       login(request, agent, backend='path.to.your.AgentBackend') 
       return redirect("agent_dashboard_url")
       ...................
```

EDIT: You can store the hashed password by overriding model save method like this.

```
class Agent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    .......

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # hash the password before saving
        self.password = make_password(self.password)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: even before I can go the to `agent_login` page, when I click the `agent login` link, it says `The view users.views.agent_login didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Comment: @sasuke seems like you removed the `else` part in your `agent_login` view. Keep other things as it is and just add those checks i posted inside `if request.method == 'POST'` block

Comment: Now returns `Invalid user credentials`. ig it returns this because my password field is a charfield where passwords aren't yet stored as hashed passwords.

Comment: @sasuke if so then you need to hash the password during the object creation.

Comment: Could you show me how to change my `agent` model so that when I create an `agent` instance in my admin panel, passwords are hashed.

Comment: @sasuke please check the answer, agent_login and model has been updated. Don't forget to remove the save_model method in your admin.py AgentAdmin class

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the `authenticate` method in `AgentBackend` returns `None` if the credentials are incorrect. That is important: if it mistakenly returns an `Agent` object even with wrong credentials, the user will be logged in.

The `authenticate` function should be called with the correct parameters (`username` and `password`), and `login` should only be called if `authenticate` returns a valid user object.

When calling `login(request, user)`, you might need to specify the backend explicitly if Django does not automatically detect the correct backend. For example, `login(request, agent, backend='users.backends.AgentBackend')`, as mentioned in [Using the Django authentication system / How to log a user in¶](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in).

As suggested in [Pycm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13861187/pycm)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77723446/6309), using the [`@login_required` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) on views that require authentication can help make sure unauthenticated access is properly managed.

Your `agent_login` would be:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import AgentSignInForm

def agent_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AgentSignInForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            agent = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if agent is not None:
                login(request, agent, backend='users.backends.AgentBackend')
                return render(request, 'users/agent_dashboard.html', {'agent': agent})
            else:
                # Add a message or logic to handle failed authentication
                pass
        else:
            # Handle invalid form
            pass
    else:
        form = AgentSignInForm()
    return render(request, 'users/agent_login.html', {'form': form})
```

Make sure the `authenticate` method correctly checks credentials and only returns an `Agent` object if the credentials are valid.
And verify that the password stored for `Agent` is hashed and that you are using Django's password hashing mechanisms, as illustrated in "[Web Security in Django – How to Build a Secure Web Application / Password Hashing](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-secure-django-web-app/#password-hashing)" by [Isah Jacob](https://twitter.com/_Jayky), using [`check_password(password, encoded, setter=None, preferred='default')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.hashers).

```py
from .models import Agent
from contextlib import suppress
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

class AgentBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        if username is None or password is None:
            return None  # Return None if credentials are missing

        with suppress(Agent.DoesNotExist):
            agent = Agent.objects.get(name=username)
            if check_password(password, agent.password):
                return agent  # Return agent if credentials are correct

        return None  # Return None if credentials are incorrect
```

As mentioned, try testing in incognito mode to avoid issues with cached sessions. Make sure the server is fully restarted after changing the backend or settings.

---

> It returns an error saying `cannot access local variable 'agent' where it is not associated with a value`

The variable `agent` might be used in a part of the code where it has not been defined or initialized yet, probably in the `agent_login` function in your `views.py`. You need to make sure `agent` is always defined before it is used.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import AgentSignInForm

def agent_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AgentSignInForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            agent = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if agent is not None:
                login(request, agent, backend='users.backends.AgentBackend')
                return redirect('dashboard')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid login credentials. Please try again.')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid form submission.')
            for field, errors in form.errors.items():
                for error in errors:
                    messages.error(request, f"{field}: {error}")
    else:
        form = AgentSignInForm()

    return render(request, 'users/agent_login.html', {'form': form})
```

The `if` statement now checks both the request method and form validation. The `authenticate` and `login` logic is inside this `if` block, ensuring `agent` is only referenced when it is defined.

The variable `agent` is now defined inside the `if` block, where it is guaranteed to have a value if the form data is valid and the authentication is successful.

The final `render` call is placed outside the `if` block to handle both initial page load (GET request) and the case where either form validation fails or authentication fails.

In your `agent_login.html` template, you need to add code to display these messages.

```html
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

The template code for displaying messages should be placed in `agent_login.html` to show feedback to the user.

---

> One thing to note here is that, on my website, agents apply to be agents where they submit their CV and details through mail to HR, then if they meet requirements an interview is scheduled and certain agents are hired. Then those agents are created by a superuser in the admin page.
>
> Here what I'm seeing is, that since the `password` field in the `agent` model is a CharField, passwords aren't really hashed, and I am not using Django's password hashing mechanisms for agents. Maybe this could be a cause for the code not working.

The fact that the `password` field in the `Agent` model is a `CharField` and that passwords are not hashed is indeed relevant: in Django, passwords should be stored in a hashed format for security reasons, and the authentication system (including `check_password`) is designed to work with hashed passwords.

The persistent "`Invalid form submission`" error could be due to the mismatch in password handling. The form expects a hashed password, but it is receiving a plain text password.

When creating an `Agent` instance (especially through the Django admin or any form), make sure the password is hashed before saving. Modify the `Agent` model to include a method for setting passwords, similar to [Django's `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords).

```py
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class Agent(models.Model):
     # existing fields 

     def set_password(self, raw_password):
          self.password = make_password(raw_password)
          self.save()
```

Use `agent.set_password(raw_password)` when creating or updating an agent's password.
Make sure when an `Agent` is created or updated through the admin, the `set_password` method is used.

Since agents are created by the superuser, revise this process to hash passwords. You might need a custom admin form for `Agent` to handle password hashing: if the form submission error persists even after ensuring password hashing, you would need to review the `AgentSignInForm`.

---

> So, after updating the code and changing the max_length of the password field to 200 so that it can store hashed values, when I create new agents or update the passwords of existing agents from admin panel, it is still stored as CharField values not hashed values.

You need to make sure the `set_password` method you have added to your `Agent` model is being used whenever an agent's password is created or updated. That is especially important in the Django admin interface, where you might need to customize the way the `Agent` model is handled.

Create a custom [ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) for your `Agent` model that handles password hashing correctly. Override the [`save_model` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods) to use the `set_password` method when saving the `Agent`.

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Agent

class AgentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Optionally, specify list_display, fieldsets, etc.

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if 'password' in form.changed_data:
            obj.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

admin.site.register(Agent, AgentAdmin)
```

In the `AgentAdmin` class, the `save_model` method is overridden. It checks if the password field has been changed (using `form.changed_data`). If the password is changed, it uses the `set_password` method to hash the new password before saving the agent. After hashing the password, it calls the superclass's `save_model` method to handle the actual saving of the agent.

Comment: It returns an error saying `cannot access local variable 'agent' where it is not associated with a value`

Comment: It now returns `agent_login.html` without any messages. So ig `That render will be used if it is a GET request or if POST fails` this render is triggered.

Comment: @sasuke OK: I have edited the code to add some error message: at least, you will see something.

Comment: Yup it returns `Invalid form submission`.

Comment: @sasuke I have updated the `agent_login` code: the additional loop within the `else` clause of the form validation check (`if form.is_valid()`) iterates through form errors and adds them to the messages. That will display more detailed information about what specifically is causing the form validation to fail.

Comment: Even after this change, it says `Invalid form submission.` without any form errors. One thing to note here is that, in my website, agents apply to be agents where they submit their CV and details through mail to HR, then if they meet requirements an interview is scheduled and certain agents are hired. Then those agents are created by a superuser in the admin page. Here what I'm seeing is, since the `password` field in `agent` model is a CharField, passwords aren't really hashed and  I am not using Django's password hashing mechanisms for agents. Maybe this could be a cause for code not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256432/discussion-between-vonc-and-sasuke).